# DAM, Digital asset management for Linux

Tags: linux, digital-asset-management

I am using Dark Table for proceesing my photos and am very happy with it, but I lack some catalog software to be able to quickly find relevant photos. Any reccomendation for software available on Linux?
BR
Bo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long wandering for several years in searching of the perfect DAM solution, I didn't find it.

However the program which comes closer (IMHO of course) and fits best for our company's needs is [XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/).

It is a cross-platform solution under active development with rather often updates (see the forums there - you can ask everything you want) with very good viewer, good editor and more than 500 file formats supported.

What differentiates it tough is:

- his powerful file management
- best in class [cataloging](http://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/Cataloging_Features_in_XnView_MP) (AFAIK of course, but I looked at almost *any* DAM solution I could find)
- search features (both on disk as well as in database)
- its [scalability](http://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/XnView_MP_-_The_most_scalable_solution)

I can say many more about this (I have enough years of experience both with this program and with other DAMs) but in order to not transform the answer in a promotional material I'll mention that we also use it in conjunction with other RAW editing back-ends (fpr reference, Photoshop CC and Photivo). It is very easy to configure XnView MP for this task: Go to `Tools | Open With... | Configure programs...`

Answer (score 3):

[digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) is something I came across as well.

Comment: When I was in the linux world, I used digikam.  It has been in more or less continuous development for over 20 years.  Good documentation.  Now it runs under windows (WINE, I think) and theres a port for Mac. Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Shotwell? It doesn't look very fancy, but it provides some cataloging/searching functionality.

Edit: Just now I found [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/), which also may meet your requirements.